# Building a reusable AngularJS directive with two-way databinding set through code

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to build a reusable directive that shows a dialog box when a button is clicked and allows the user to customize an array of strings. I have this working fine in a single-use-case scenario, but I'm trying to figure out if I can create two-way data binding through code, so that I can use a single instance of this directive multiple times with different arrays of strings.

In my HTML, I have the directive (note the lack of binding to a particular array):

`<my-array-dialog control='arrayDialog'></my-array-dialog>`

I'm exposing a shared control object with a showDialog method on it that causes the dialog to be shown. An example of that pattern is: http://plnkr.co/edit/MqN9yS8R5dnqTfjqldwX?p=preview

What I want to do is have two-way data-binding with the parent controller passing in the data into my showDialog method. I'm unsure how to configure this though, or even if it is possible.

In my directive, I have the following:

```
$scope.control = {
    showDialog: function (arrayData) {
        // Ideally, this would create two-way data binding
        $scope.arrayData = arrayData;
        // Manipulate the DOM here to show the dialog
    }
}
```

Ideally, changes to `$scope.arrayData` would be reflected in the calling code's arrayData. Again, the reason I'm not setting this up as an attribute is because I want to call this dialog multiple times with different data and to avoid having multiple dialog directive instances.

Is it possible to set up the two-way data binding in this manner, or am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely! Check out the intimidating yet incredibly helpful AngularJS docs page on [$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile). In particular, what it sounds like you'd like to do is create a two-way binding between a parent scope variable and a variable in the local scope of the directive.

When defining a directive, you can specify a scope object. You'll want to create an isolate scope (for reusability) and use the `@` feature to create the two-way bindings with the HTML attributes.

From the $compile docs:

> = or =attr - set up bi-directional binding between a local scope property and the parent scope property of name defined via the value of the attr attribute. If no attr name is specified then the attribute name is assumed to be the same as the local name. Given  and widget definition of scope: { localModel:'=myAttr' }, then widget scope property localModel will reflect the value of parentModel on the parent scope. Any changes to parentModel will be reflected in localModel and any changes in localModel will reflect in parentModel.

Comment: I will look into $compile, thank you. I'll report back if that solves my problem.

Comment: @BrianVallelunga - any luck with the proposed solution?